# Trouble with Pod Descheduler: Pods in 'CrashLoopBackOff' not being evicted

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I am currently utilizing the Pod Descheduler, as a cronjob, sourced from the official GitHub repository at 'https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler/tree/release-1.25', within a Kubernetes 1.25 cluster version. To configure its behavior, I am leveraging the following values within the associated ConfigMap.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: descheduler-policy-configmap
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  policy.yaml: |
    apiVersion: "descheduler/v1alpha1"
    kind: "DeschedulerPolicy"
    evictFailedBarePods: false
    strategies:
      "RemoveDuplicates":
        enabled: true
      "RemovePodsViolatingInterPodAntiAffinity":
        enabled: true
      "LowNodeUtilization":
        enabled: true
        params:
          nodeResourceUtilizationThresholds:
            thresholds:
              "cpu" : 20
              "memory": 20
              "pods": 20
            targetThresholds:
              "cpu" : 50
              "memory": 50
              "pods": 50
      "RemoveFailedPods":
        enabled: true
        params:
          failedPods:
            reasons:
            - OutOfcpu
            - CreateContainerConfigError
            - Evicted
            - Unhealthy
            - Error
            - Completed
            - BackOff
            includingInitContainers: true
            # excludeOwnerKinds:
            # - "Job"
            minPodLifetimeSeconds: 120 # 1 hour
            failed_pods_with_reason:
            - CrashLoopBackOff
      "PodLifeTime":
        enabled: true
        params:
          podLifeTime:
            maxPodLifeTimeSeconds: 60 # 7 days
            states:
            - "Pending"
            - "PodInitializing"
            - "ContainerCreating"
      "RemovePodsHavingTooManyRestarts":
        enabled: true
        params:
          podsHavingTooManyRestarts:
            podRestartThreshold: 5
            includingInitContainers: true
            runningPods:
              enabled: false
            failedPods:
              enabled: true
```

Given the fact that I have placed "CrashLoopBackOff" under failedPods > reasons as well. Still not being able to evict the pods.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to push out a YAML file in a ConfigMap.  What code have you written that uses this data?  What programming-related problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am implementing a descheduler in Kubernetes using yaml and from given project with guidance 'https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/descheduler/tree/release-1.25'. When I implement the descheduler passing down these values above, it will implement descheduler policies of my liking. But these strategies are not evicting pods for all reasons like pods with status ContainerStatusUnknown or CrashLoopBackOff.